# Magento - Category Custom Layout Update

Tags: php, magento, layout

I want to add a custom CMS Block into my category per category. So I created a Custom CMS Block: 
Title: TestBlock
Identifier: testblock

Then I enter into my category and under Custom Design Tab - in the Custom Layout Update textarea, I add the following

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="TestBlock" after="catalog.compare.sidebar">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>testblock</block_id></action>
    </block>    
</reference>
```

This adds the content of my custom CMS Block in the sidebar, but the positioning is wrong. Instead of adding it at the bottom of the sidebar (last block is the Compare Products), it ends up at the top. Any ideas how to position it properly? I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try not using "after" in your block, it may work.

Comment: didn't help - any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may try as per following.

`<reference name="left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="TestBlock" after="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>testblock</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>`

Comment: tried that - didn't work... I have a feeling it's a theme related... any way i can bypass that? Can I provide any other relevant code or info?